# Primitive Permutation Group and Centralizers

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

[Automorphism group of the Alternating Group - a proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1049663/automorphism-group-of-the-alternating-group-a-proof/1049847#1049847)

In the above question, Derek Holt asserts that a primitive permutation groups has trivial centraliser in the symmetric group. Since I could not understand why, I thought to open a new question (maybe someone like me could be interested in this). Is there any simple proof of this?

Comment: I do not know a lot about groups of permutations. If $G$ has order prime we cannot saying anything, right? The orbit of $X$ are blocks for $G$ and so $X$ must be transitive (since $G$ is primitive). Why $X$ permutes the fixed points of $g$ for any $g\in G$? and how it follows that no non-identity element of $G$ fixes any point?

Comment: You should be able to prove yourself that if two permutations $g$ and $h$ commute, then $g$ permutes the fixed points of $h$, and vice versa.

Comment: Just a minor point: you don't need to assume that $n$ is not prime, but just that $|G|$ is not prime, which is a weaker assumption.

Comment: @Geoff Robinson: Maybe you can update your solution as the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure whether clarifying an answer to an earlier question merits a formal answer ( and I have incorporated a minor point made by Derek in this answer anyway), but here goes : First of all, groups of prime order $p$ in $S_{p}$ are an exception, as Derek pointed out in his answer to the previous question. Suppose then that $G$ is a primitive subgroup of $S_n$ which is not of prime order,  and let $X$ be the centralizer of $G.$ Then $G$ permutes the orbits of $X$, so if $X≠1$, then $X$ is transitive. Now $X$ permutes the fixed points of $g$ for any $g∈G$, so no non-identity element of $G$ fixes any point. Hence $G$ is regular (since it is transitive). Hence the trivial subgroup of $G$ is maximal, so $G$ has prime order, contrary to assumption.